# Show that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=p$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. Let $p$ be the smallest integer so that $A=BC$ for some $m \times p$ matrix $B$ and some $p \times n$ matrix $C$.

I want to show that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=p$.

**My attempt:**

Take $v \in \operatorname{Col}(A)$, where $\operatorname{Col}(A)$ denotes the column space of $A$. So $v=Ax$ for some $x$. This implies that $v=BCx=B(Cx) \in \operatorname{Col}(B)$. Thus $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq \operatorname{rank}(B) \leq p$.

I guess I now need to show that $\operatorname{rank}(A) \geq p$, I'm not sure how to do this though.

Comment: HINT: $p$ is the smallest number such that "*something*": this means that $p \le$ something. Consider the epimorphism $f_A : k^n \to Ak^n$ given by $v \mapsto Av$, and then the inclusion $i: Ak^n \to k^m$.

Comment: @Crostul Hmm. I'm not quite sure how to use your hint. I understand what you're saying but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: What you need to show is that for any matrix of rank $p$, there *exists* a factorization $AB$ in which $A$ is $n \times p$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Is this not the converse of what I want to show?

Comment: @user332597 no.  What you've already shown is that for any such factorization, $A$ must have at least $p$ columns.

Comment: Sorry, I mean a factorization $BC$ in which $B$ is $n \times p$.  And of course, for any such factorization, you've shown that $B$ has at least $p$ columns.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I've looked up a proof of what you suggested and I'm happy with that now. However, I'm still confused about the logic side of it. That is, I've shown that if $A=BC$ then $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq p$ and if $\operatorname{rank}(A)=p$ then $A=BC$. It doesn't make sense to me why this implies that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=p$ though.

Comment: Remember: $p$ is the **smallest** integer for which there exist such $B$ and $C$.  If rank $A$ were lower, we could get $A = BC$ with smaller matrices $B$ and $C$